# Directive has access to DOM when code is in same file as controller but not in directive specific file

Tags: file, csv, hyperlink, upload, directive

I am using a simple file upload directive and I wanted to place it into its own file. However when I remove the directive specific code from the controllers file the link function isn't called at all.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" file-change="handler($event,files)" ng-model="fileModel" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('GenericController', function($scope, $http, $filter, Constants, GenericObject) {

    $scope.csv="";

    $scope.uploadCSVFile = function(){
        var csv = $scope.file;
        GenericObject.create(Constants.url,csv);
    };

    //Method to obtain the files contents. They will be held in the string object 
    //that is generated when an event is detected.
    $scope.handler=function(e,files) { 
        var reader=new FileReader();  
        reader.onload=function(e){ 
            $scope.file = reader.result; //$scope.file is populated with the uploaded file text
        }
        reader.readAsText(files[0]); //Will read the file and then populate result in reader
    };

});

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//Code To Be Moved, when moved, the link function is no longer called.
//TODO: move to uploadDirective.js
//Directive for the csv Upload
angular.module('myApp').directive('fileChange',['$parse', function($parse){
  return{
    require:'ngModel',
    restrict:'A',
    link:function($scope,element,attrs,ngModel){
      var attrHandler=$parse(attrs['fileChange']);
      var handler=function(e){
        $scope.$apply(function(){
          attrHandler($scope,{$event:e,files:e.target.files});
        });
      };
      element[0].addEventListener('change',handler,false);
    }
  }
}]);
```

So the above works fine when it's all in one block as shown, but does not work when the directive is in it's own file. Any ideas?

I should add that yes, the directive code is view-able in debug perspective.
I am curious as to if there is any weirdness when you create a directive and have placed it in it's separate file from the controller if is used in that you need to do so it will play nice.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was the include order of the files. Always include your libraries first, followed by your application configuration file, followed by your controllers and then directives etc.

e.g. index.jsp

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src=app/app.js>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=app/controller.js>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=app/directive.js>
```